# Undefined errors with ObjectKey and collection.doc

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I cloned a repository from GitHub for a flutter project. The developer uses a old Firebase version and was giving me undefined class errors. I updated the Cloud Firestore and Firebase core to the latest version but I am still getting undefined class errors.

**These are the two lines which cause the problem**

```
key: ObjectKey(docs.data.keys)
collection.doc(doc.documentID).delete();
```

**And these are the errors-**

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'keys'.
                      key: ObjectKey(docs.data.keys),
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'doc'.
                        collection.doc(doc.documentID).delete();
```

some **name** has been changed in the latest update but I cannot find it.

Comment: Please explain what you were doing and changed to produce this error, and provide more context to your question, either the GitHub project or a larger portion of code so that the error can be reproduced

Comment: I am using a github repository for a flutter project. The firebase version in the app is old version so i update it with latest version dependencies. Due to the latest update, some namefields are throwing error in the code. Here the github repository [link](https://github.com/perpetio/clubhouse)

Comment: Your first line it's not in the [Github](https://github.com/perpetio/clubhouse/search?q=ObjectKey%28docs.data.keys%29) you shared. What I found is [that one](https://github.com/perpetio/clubhouse/blob/bb66667420a9c45c92eb265aa4d240d2426e6d60/lib/screens/home/rooms_list.dart#L175). 

Also, your second line isn't also there and [this](https://github.com/perpetio/clubhouse/blob/bb66667420a9c45c92eb265aa4d240d2426e6d60/lib/screens/home/rooms_list.dart#L177) is the closest one. Did you change any code? If so, please share a snippet of your code.

Comment: No i didn't change any code, I tried it just after copy the repository but it didn't work that way too. you can try it the way it is in the github. @AntonL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question. As it's a old question and i'm not working in that project anymore. So i'm closing this project.